# How do you name a folder on the home screen (Gingerbread, HTC Incredible)?

Tags: home-screen-folders

I added a folder to the home screen, but it's automatically labeled "folder." If I have multiple folders, it will get confusing. How can I change the name of the folder?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Tap to open the folder, then long-press the text making up the name. That should change it to an editable field.